# GridView FocusedRowChanged - Child Class object

Tags: c#, events, gridview, devexpress

I need some help here.

I've created a child class called MyEditorRow from DevExpress EditorRow, and added 3 properties

```
public class myEditorRow : EditorRow
    {
        public myEditorRow()
        {
        }

        private string inRowDescription = null;
        public string RowDescription
        {
            get { return inRowDescription; }
            set { inRowDescription = value; }
        }

        private bool inRequired = false;
        public bool Required
        {
            get { return inRequired; }
            set { inRequired = value; }
        }

        private bool inInherits = false;
        public bool Inherits
        {
            get { return inInherits; }
            set { inInherits = value; }
        }
```

Second part of the code somewhere in the program adds instance of MyEditorRow to DevExpress VGrid Control.

```
vgcGrid.Rows.Add(Row);
```

My question is this: How can I link MyEditorRow class with DevExpress VGrid Control FocusedRowChanged event, so I can get my custom properties when row focus changes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The e.Row parameter is of the BaseRow type.  So, to obtain an instance of the MyEditorRow object in the FocusnedRowChanged event handler, use the following code:

```
private void vGridControl1_FocusedRowChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraVerticalGrid.Events.FocusedRowChangedEventArgs e) {
    if(e.Row is myEditorRow) {
        myEditorRow row = ((myEditorRow)e.Row);
        // your code here
    }       
}
```